# MySQL Datatype for storing bloodtype?

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

Which MySQL datatype would be preferable (the smallest amount of data needed) for storing blood types?  In other words, storing one to two letters with the '+' or '-' symbol.

Thanks

Comment: whatever you are happy with

Comment: My first thought is an ENUM, with the possible values. (A+, A-, B+, B-, AB+, etc...) There are some [caveats](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/) to using an ENUM. Also, since it's such a small bit of data, VARCHAR(3) should also work just fine.

Comment: I vote for `ENUM` _for this use case_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's highly dependent on your needs and wants. Personally, I'd probably go with assigning a numeric value to each type and using `tinyint`. However, if you want the rows more directly readable `CHAR(3)` or `VARCHAR(3)` might be more appropriate. In fact, this is one of the few rare cases where I would even suggest using an `ENUM` (as it is very very unlikely you'll ever need to add or remove from possible values).

Comment: I hadn't even thought of using ENUM for it, though it would be a good choice for this column as well as a few others that there are specific options for.  Thank you

Comment: I'd caution against using enum in most cases though; it is actually kind of rare in my experience for the list of valid values to not need expanded later, and requiring an alter table on years of data can be painful. That and support for enum types in various db access libraries can be a bit lacking.

Comment: @Uueerdo -- That caution is out of date.  A few versions ago, `ALTERing` an `ENUM` became very efficient -- _if_ you are only _adding_ new values on the _end_.

Comment: `CHAR(3)` is wasteful of space, especially if your default charset is utf8.

Comment: @RickJames given the size and cost of modern hard drives, even ssds laterly, that is hardly a concern. It is only 3 characters, 2 of which are guaranteed to be used. That leaves the 3rd that (assuming a distribution of data corresponding to nature) will be only used 4% of the time; but varchar will also use a byte to specify length. When the math is done, varchar would save 2.84 bytes per row; or cost a MB every ~360000 rows. An enum would save more, but is not worth the relatively eccentric behavior it can exhibit at times, and spotty support in db APIs that would need to be dealt with.

Comment: If space (or speed) is that much of a concern, `tinyint` would be the best option. It could even be encoded from a 3 bit value indicating A[yes|no]|B[yes|no]|positive[yes|no], with 0 being O negative.

Comment: Of course, you'd have no need to use utf-8 for such a field, in which case VARCHAR would actually *cost* more space.

Comment: `CHAR(3)` would cost more space for utf8 -- always 9 bytes; `VARCHAR(3)` would not, it would be 3-4 bytes, regardless of `CHARACTER SET` (assuming blood types use only English characters).

Comment: @RickJames Ah, nevermind, I see; I assumed MySQL took the easier route of reserving/using 3 bytes to store each character even with utf8. I've never had much call to use utf-8, and definitely wouldn't for this kind of field at least.

Comment: All too many people casually say `uuid CHAR(36)` in a table defaulting to utf8, especially now that utf8 is the system-wide default.  So I harp on the issue.  With `utf8mb4` becoming the standard, the multiplier will become 4 (instead of 3).

Comment: In those situations I can definitely see the concern.